# Bookshelf Data Structures Issues

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I am making a bookshelf of width size s(1<s<100). Add book id and the book width at the leftmost of the vector. If you add a book which causes the width to be exceeded, then delete the rightmost book until the book to be added can be put on the shelf. In the end, the remaining books on the bookshelf can be added.

The issue I am facing that when var = 'E' the program should display the remaining books on the shelf and then exit that problem and go to a different problem, but when 'E' is entered the remaining books on the shelf will not display, and the program will not exit. I have tried messing with the while loops condition that is nested in the overall while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct book{
    int id;
    int w;
};

int main(){
//std::vector::~vector
    //create instance of book
    book my_book;
    //initialize the placeholders
    int s, removed_book, back_width;
    char var;
    //create the vector 
    vector<book>shelf;
    while(true){
        //enter the s value 
        s = 0;
        cout << "enter the s value: " << endl;
        cin >> s;
        int w_total = 0;

        //be able to exit the program
        if(s == -1){
            return 0;
        }
        int x = 1;
        //while remaining space
        while(x!=0){              //need to fix this up

            cout << "enter the action(A,R,E): " << endl;
            cin >> var >> my_book.id >> my_book.w;


            //if A
            if(var == 'A'){
                //get info about the book
                /*
                cout << "enter id: " << endl;
                cin >> my_book.id;
                cout << "width(w): " << endl;
                cin >> my_book.w;
                */
                w_total += my_book.w;
                shelf.insert(shelf.begin(),my_book);
                cout << "total width(1): " << w_total << endl;

                if(w_total > s){
                    while(w_total >= s){
                        //remove the rightmost(back) book
                        w_total = w_total - shelf.back().w;
                        cout << "total width(2): " << w_total << endl;
                        shelf.erase(shelf.end()-1);
                    }
                }
            }
            //if R
            else if(var == 'R'){
                //cout << "which book to be removed? : " << endl;
                //cin >> removed_book;
                removed_book = my_book.id;
                for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
                    if(shelf[i].id == removed_book){
                        shelf.erase(shelf.begin()+i);      
                    }
                }
            }
            //if E
            else if(var == 'E'){
                cout << "remaining books on shelf: " << endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < shelf.size(); i++){
                    if(shelf[i].id!=0){
                        cout << "id: "<<shelf[i].id << endl;
                    }   
                }
                //maybe put the display in here?
                x = 1;  
            }
        }
        //print out the remaining shelf

        shelf.clear(); 
        //erase the shelfs(vectors) contents
        //increase problem number
    }
return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
10(shelf width)
A 1 3(Add id width)
A 2 5
E
-->PROBLEM 1: 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`cin >> var >> my_book.id >> my_book.w` is asking the user to enter three things: a character and two integers.  You have to enter all three before the action in `var` will be checked and acted upon.